# If function not triggering after Boolean change?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

I have a system where once a certain key is pressed, a Boolean changes to true and the program should trigger an if loop. However, once the key is pressed, the program 'locks up' and is unresponsive. (The program *should* be automatically moving the paddle, and the whole thing *should* be able to be turned off, but it seems as though it simply isn't activating.
Here's the offending code:

```
var aienable = false;
$(document).keydown(function(keyPressed){
    if (keyPressed.keyCode == 192 && aienable == false){
        aienable = true;
    }
});
if (aienable == true){
    var AIdrive = setInterval(function(){
        $(document).keydown(function(keyPressed){
            if (keyPressed.keyCode == 192 && aienable == true){
                aienable = false;
            }
        });
        if (aienable == false){
            clearInterval(AIdrive);
        }
    },1000);
}
```

Note: The key used is `

Comment: The `if` statement needs to be **inside** the event handler. Otherwise it will only run once, when that block of code is first interpreted.

Comment: Also adding a new "keydown" handler in an interval timer callback is going to be a disaster. When you add a new handler, previously-added handlers are **not** removed.

Comment: if it is a game, and you have a function `fn` set up by `setInterval()` to alter the position of objects, then your keyDown handler can just alter some variables to let the paddle move left or right. Otherwise if it is just to press a key and start something, then your keyDown can just invoke `setInterval()` to do something. It depends on what you want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your code

`if (aienable == true){`

is executed **once**, just after

`var aienable = false;`

And the condition is always false.
**Changing value** of `aienable` is executed **when You press a key**.

Secondary `if` should be inside keydown event handler just after first `if`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put the boolean condition code in a function and call it from inside the key down handler. the variable has value true after key pressing but the code is not being notified that as it has already been run.